# Secret Token Error in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, token

I'm running into this error on a new Rails app and it has me a bit confused.  I can start the rails server and load the index page just fine, but when I try to load any other page I get

ArguemntError: A secret is required to generate an integrity hash for cookie session data. Use config.secret_token = "some secret phrase of at least 30 characters"in config/initializers/secret_token.rb

Now what makes this strange is that I have verified that I do indeed have a .secret file.  I modified the secret_token.rb file to generate a random .secret file as per the Mike Hartl tutorial.  I have checked that the .secret file does indeed exist.  In fact, I deleted it and restarted the server just to make sure it would generate a new one, and it did.  The contents of the .secret file do indeed contain a string of greater than 30 characters. And yet I am getting this error.  I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

I did some googling and it appears that some felt this error was related to a race condition caused by accessing the site too soon after starting the server.  I restarted the server, waiting five minutes, and then accessed the site.  Same issue.  I am at a loss to understand why I am getting this error.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this on rails 3 or 4? In Rails 4 my line secret_token.rb is AppName::Application.config.secret_key_base = 'XXXXX'

Comment: That is the default, yes.  However, it isn't very secure, particularly when you are using repositories such as gitHub.  The point was to move away from having a hard-coded token.

Comment: Oh sorry I somehow missed the part where you said you modified it. Have you ensured that AppName is indeed the name of your app? Could you try defaulting back to the normal method and see if the error still occurs to narrow it down to something wrong within that function or something larger than that.

Comment: @AlthafHameez, I thought in Rails 4 secret_token.rb is no longer produced?  And that secrets.yml is what replaced it?  Do we just treat secrets.yml the same as secret_token.rb? I'm kind of stucked at this part.

Answer (score 0):

I had to switch last line of secret_token.rb from:

```
SampleApp::Application.config.secret_key_base = secure_token
```

to:

```
Todo::Application.config.secret_token = secure_token
```

Took reading the error message over and over though.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have this in your environment.rb:

```
YourApp::Application.initialize!
```